# Evaluating functional derivatives

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I am new to evaluating functional derivatives and I am having difficulty evaluating the following derivative:

$$I = \frac{\delta}{\delta x(t)}\frac{\delta}{\delta x(t')}\int_{u_i}^{u_f}\frac{du}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)^2~.$$

I have tried to do it and I obtain the following:

$$I = -\frac{\delta}{\delta x(t)}\frac{d^2x}{du^2}\delta(t'-u)~,$$

but I am not sure how to take the second derivative and am actually not sure if what I've done so far is right either.

How can this derivative be evaluated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am having difficulty evaluating the following derivative:
>
> $$I = \frac{\delta}{\delta x(t)}\frac{\delta}{\delta x(t')}\int_{u_i}^{u_f}\frac{du}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)^2~.$$
>
> ... How can this derivative be evaluated?

I will define a functional called F
$$
F[x] = \int_{u_i}^{u_f}\frac{du}{2}\left(\frac{dx}{du}\right)^2
\equiv \int_{u_i}^{u_f}\frac{du}{2}\left(\dot x(u)\right)^2\;.
$$

Consider this functional $F$ evaluated at $x(u)+\delta x(u)$, where we are planning to expand in a power series in $\delta x$. We have:
$$
F[x+\delta x] = F[x] + \int du \dot x(u)\dot {\delta x(u)} + \frac{1}{2}\int du \dot {\delta x(u)}\dot {\delta x(u)}\tag{A}\;.
$$
Here, the power series expansion is exact after three terms since the function is just a quadratic function.

Also, by definition of the first and second functional derivatives we have:
$$
F[x+\delta x] = F[x] + \int du {\delta x(u)}\frac{\delta F}{\delta x(u)} +\frac{1}{2!} \int du du' {\delta x(u)}\delta x(u') \frac{\delta^2 F}{\delta x(u)\delta x(u')}+\ldots\;.\tag{B}
$$

For example, in order to identify the first functional derivative by comparing Eq. (A) to Eq. (B), we need to put the linear term in Eq. (A) into the correct form by integrating by parts.

For example, in order to  identify the second functional derivative by comparing Eq. (A) to Eq. (B), we need to insert a delta function and integrate by parts twice
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int du \dot {\delta x(u)}\dot{\delta x(u)}
= \frac{1}{2}\int du du' \delta(u-u')\dot {\delta x(u)}\dot{\delta x(u')}
= -\frac{1}{2}\int du du' \ddot{\delta}(u-u')\delta x(u)\delta x(u')
$$
to see that
$$
\frac{\delta^2 F}{\delta x(u)\delta x(u')} = -\ddot{\delta}(u-u')
$$

---

This can also be arrived at by first taking the first functional derivative of $F$ and then taking another functional derivative of the result:
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta x(u)}[x] = -\ddot x(u) = -\int du' \ddot x(u')\delta(u-u') 
$$
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta x(u)}[x+\delta x] = \frac{\delta F}{\delta x(u)}[x]-\int du' \delta(u-u')\ddot {\delta x(u')}
$$
$$
=\frac{\delta F}{\delta x(u)}[x] - \int du \ddot{\delta}(u-u')\delta x(u')
$$
thus
$$
\frac{\delta }{\delta x(u')}\frac{\delta F}{\delta x(u)} = -\ddot{\delta}(u-u')
$$